# Check if two generic types are equal

Tags: c#, generics, types

I need to find if a type is a certain generic type.

```
class MyType<T> {}
var instance = new MyType<int>();
var type = instance.GetType();
```

This check does not work, but this is what I want to check. If the type is of that generic type, regardless of what `T` is.

```
type == typeof( MyType<> )
```

This does work, but feels dirty. It could also be wrong since it's not the `FullName`.

```
type.Name == typeof( MyType<> ).Name
```

I'm assuming there is a way to do this, but I haven't found one. Using `IsAssignableFrom` will not work, because I need to know if the current type, and not one of it's parents, are equal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work if the concrete type of the object is `MyType<T>`. It will not work for instances of types derived from `MyType<T>`, and will not work if `MyType<T>` is an interface type.

```
if (type.IsGenericType
    && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyType<>))
```